# Finding correct filesize over 4gb in windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I have used this c++ code to find the filesize of some files in windows(using visual studio):

```
(p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh * MAXDWORD) + p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow);
```

This did not give me the correct filesize if the file was greater than 4gb. After some research I tried:

```
(p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh * (MAXDWORD+1)) + p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow);
```

as I read that nfilesizehigh and nfilesizelow are 32 bits each of 64 bit value of the filesize and if the filesize value is greater than 32 bits, we multiply maxdword(which in my case is 0xffffffff) by nfilesizehigh. The second solution also did not work and gave me a smaller size than what it was. I again tried this:

```
ULONGLONG FileSize = (FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh * 4294967296) + FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
```

and it worked. Also I used another solution to get the file size too along with this:

```
 ULONGLONG FileSize = FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh;
 FileSize <<= sizeof( FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh ) *8; 
 FileSize |= FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
```

The above solution works too:

I wanted to know why the first 2 solutions did not work and also the explanation for the last solution if possible as I want to know the internal working of the code. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use :

```
ULONGLONG FileSize = (static_cast<ULONGLONG>(FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh) <<
                      sizeof(FindFileData.nFileSizeLow) *8) |
                     FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
```

The cast to ULONGLONG is necessary to make the 32-bit value into a 64-bit value BEFORE it goes into the FileSize variable.

You can of course use a multiplication too - but it isn't "better" in any particular way, and most likely a tiny bit slower [probably no big deal in this particular case, but there's no benefit in using multiply that I can see.

And now for the "not working" variants:

Even if this DOES work:

```
 (p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh * MAXDWORD) + p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow);
```

you'd get the wrong value, since `MAXDWORD` is one smaller than 4GB, so you end up with the wrong value [yes, it's perhaps close, but it will be at the very least 1 byte wrong, possibly a lot more]. However, since we're dealing with 32-bit values, it actually becomes:

```
 -p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh + p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow;
```

because `MAXDWORD` is the same as -1 (yes, it may well be an unsigned value, but if you make the value overflow that way, it behaves just the same as a negative signed value).

This one is mathematically correct, but doesn't work due to the fact that it overflows a 32-bit value.

```
 (p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh * (MAXDWORD+1)) + p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow);
```

So you get the `low part + (0 * high part)` which of course is incorrect.

With cast, this will work:

```
 static_cast<ULONGLONG>(p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh) * (MAXDWORD+1) +
 p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow;
```

Comment: Hi Mats, thanks very much for the detailed answer. I appreciate that. Also I had some questions like: why do we multiply the filesizehigh by MAXDWORD or 4gb in the not working variants? What is the logic behind that? And in the first code why do we multiply the filesizehigh by 8?

Comment: `MAXDWORD` = (2^32)-1` [where `^` = to the power of, not C's XOR symbol], so one away from 4GB. And `sizeof(FileSizeHigh) * 8` is the number of bits in FileSizeHigh` (32). A left-shift (`<<`) is the same as multiplying by `2^32`. Actually, I think the correct thing to do would actually be to shift by `sizeof(FileSizeLow) * 8`, since that's the number of bits in the low part - it is also 32 bits, but if ever someone changes `FileSizeLow` or `FileSizeHigh` to be 64 bits, the math will continue to work [except you need something bigger than `ULONGLONG` to store it.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work: static_cast<ULONGLONG>(p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh) * (MAXDWORD+1) +
 p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow;

Comment: You may need a `(static_cast<ULONGLONG>(MAXDWORD)+1)` to avoid it becoming `0` (it's a bit like the odometer on a car, if you've done 99999 miles, it flips over to 00000 the next time - same with all ones in binary).

Comment: :) Yeah Tried that yesterday and understood what was happening. Thanks for the explanation Mats.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `ULARGE_INTEGER` struct to combine the values, instead of trying to calculate/shift them manually:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
ul.HighPart = p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh;
ul.LowPart = p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow;
ULONGLONG FileSize = ul.QuadPart;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh * MAXDWORD) + p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow);
```

This does not give the right result because MAXDWORD is the wrong value.

```
(p_findFileData->nFileSizeHigh * (MAXDWORD+1)) + p_findFileData->nFileSizeLow);
```

This does not work because you are adding +1 to MAXDWORD before casting the type to something big enough to hold the value.

```
(FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh * 4294967296) + FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
```

This works because `4294967296` is a 64 bit type.

```
FileSize <<= sizeof( FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh ) *8; 
FileSize |= FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
```

This works because you shift the high bits by 32 (which is identical to multiplying by 4294967296) and then 'add' the low bits using  bitwise or.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Thomas. Can you also tell me why do we multiply filesizehigh by 8 in the last code and why is the MAXDWORD wrong size in the 1st code? What should it be if its a wrong size? Please let me know if possible.

Comment: MAXDWORD is 4294967295. The right value is 4294967296. MAXDWORD+1 however is 0 (if in 2s complement) and not 4294967296. To be able to add 1 and get 4294967296 as a result you must cast it into a 64 bit value first.

Comment: Personally, I consider hard-coding magic values like that to be a bad idea; the need for your explanatory comment should highlight the issue with this particular magic value. In my opinion it's much more sensible (and easy to understand) to cast `FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh` to a `ULONGLONG`, shift it left and add `FindFileData.nFileSizeLow`

Comment: Your not going to get around magic here, it makes no difference whether your magic number is 8, 32, or 2^32.

Comment: Makes sense...thanks very much Thomas and Nik for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and the answer was really easy for my code. Just cast MAXDWORD to a 64 bit int (eg uint64_t). The explanation behind this can be found in the answers I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53152486/uint64-t-t3-maxdword-1-0).