# uint64_t t3 = MAXDWORD + 1 == 0?

Tags: c++

I really don't understand what is happening with the code below. Why is `t3` zero?

```
uint64_t t1 = MAXDWORD;         // t1 contains 4294967295 - CORRECT
uint64_t t2 = t1 + 1;           // t2 contains 4294967296 - CORRECT
uint64_t t3 = MAXDWORD + 1;     // t3 contains 0 (zero)   - HUH??
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`decltype(MAXDWORD)` is a narrower type than `uint64_t`. So the expression `MAXDWORD + 1` is not a `uint64_t` either, and `unsigned` wraparound behaviour is observed *prior* to the assignment to `t3`.

`t1 + 1` is performed in `unsigned` arithmetic using the `uint64_t` type, which is wider.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I think that `MAXDWORD` is 32 bit and not 64 bit since 4294967295 is the max size of a 32 bit unsigned integer.  Therefore the expression `MAXDWORD + 1` is the sum of two 32 bit values which is only upgraded to 64 bit **after** evaluation. Therefore it will overflow back to zero.

`t1 + 1` on the other hand is a 64 bit and a 32 bit expression.  The 32 bit constant is upgraded to 64 bits and then evaluated.  This therefore does not overflow.

Give the bellow expressions a try and see if you can figure out which ones will overflow...

```
uint64_t t4 = MAXDWORD + 1LL;
uint64_t t5 = (uint64_t)MAXDWORD + 1;
uint64_t t6 = MAXDWORD + (uint64_t)1;
uint64_t t7 = (uint64_t)(MAXDWORD + 1);
```

Comment: The literal `1` is not necessarily a 32 bit expression, but I know what you're saying.

Comment: True.  I guess I am just used to assuming it is.

Comment: "*In this case I think that `MAXDWORD` is 32 bit and not 64 bit since 4294967295 is the max size of a 32 bit unsigned integer*" - `MAXDWORD` is just a macro that defines an [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal): `#define MAXDWORD 0xffffffff`. As you can see, there is no type suffix specified, and a 32bit unsigned integer is the smallest allowed type that `0xffffffff` fits in, so that is what the compiler uses.